# Comparing last character(s) of the output of \ref to manipulate output

Tags: cross-referencing, etoolbox, xparse, strings

I am trying to write a command that will replace `\ref` in a special way. It will add some text next to the number based on the last character(s) of the number `\ref` outputs.

I will try to explain this with an example:

- If the last character of `\ref` output is 1 (like if it is 11, 21, etc.) then the output shall be "1'de" instead of "1"
- Similarly if the last character of `\ref` output is 5 (like if it is 5, 15, etc.) then the output shall be "5'te" instead of "5"
- If the last character is "0" then, the code should check last 2 characters. It will output something for 10 and another thing for 20 and so on.

So the spec goes like this:

- 1: 1'de
- 2: 2'de
- 3: 3'te
- 4: 4'te
- 5: 5'te
- 6: 6'da
- 7: 7'de
- 8: 8'de
- 9: 9'da
- 10: 10'da
- 20: 20'de
- 30: 30'da
- ...

It goes on forever. I will cut at some point.

I am stuck at the beginning. I couldn't get the output of `\ref{}` to compare it with anything. I tried the following as a first trial using `etoolbox` and `xparse`but unfortunately failed to compare:

```
\NewDocumentCommand \reftr {m g}{%
\ref{#1}%Outputs the output of \ref with no problem
\IfNoValueTF{#2}{}{%
    \expandafter\ifstrequal{\ref{#1}}{1}{'de}{'??} %this should at least give me 'de for the first crossref but it doesn't.
}%
}%
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you give the complete specification? What if the number ends with another digit?

Comment: ok i am editing

Comment: I already solved the problem! It reminded me of something!

Comment: Ok this definitely is a duplicate. I somehow couldn't find it. What do I do? delete the question all together?

Comment: No it will be closed if more people vote on it. So no worries :)

Comment: :) ok. But my approach to the problem is little different actually. This is something i can do in python in minutes but somehow LaTeX is so hard when it comes to adding some functionality.

Comment: @Sinan Python doesn't typeset.

Comment: @egreg that is why I am here.